# PHP max simultaneously Script Calls... (Scheduler ?) NOT CRON

Tags: php, queue, scheduler

Hey I am trying to figure out how to limit the maximum simultaneously calls of a specific script in PHP. 
I make an API Call which creates Endpoints in another System. These Endpoints are limited! 
And after the script execution they are deleted again. So I want the clients requesting the Script to be enqued until there are Endpoints free.

Any suggestions for me ? 
Thanks

Comment: As long as you don't have to worry about race conditions for accessing it, you can just create a file that contains the number of currently-active endpoints. Then reference that when running the script, before making the API call.

Comment: This not how you ask a question. You should not ask for a whole project or code. You should work on your code and put what have you done so far, here. Read the Help Center topics to learn more about what questions you can ask and what type of questions you have to avoid. [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Community will definitely be glad to help you for right questions.